# how to call a onclick function in <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open a new window on click of 1

```
$leadID = "<a href='javascript:onclick=window.open(lead_data.php?leadid=1, myWin, scrollbars=yes, width=400, height=650);'>1</a>";
```

It is not showing me error. Is there any other way to open new window?

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ankurdhanuka/uwypv/

Comment: You can use `target="_blank"` to open new window.

Comment: give reason for down vote

Comment: Well, I didn't downvoted but you are gettings these because your question is a low quality post

Comment: @ĐēēpakShãrmã how to increase quality of post?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try onclick function separately it can give you access to execute your function which can be used to open up a new window, for this purpose you first need to create a javascript function there you can define it and in your anchor tag you just need to call your function.

**Example:**

```
function newwin() {              
 myWindow=window.open('lead_data.php?leadid=1','myWin','width=400,height=650')
}
```

See how to call it from your anchor tag

```
<a onclick='newwin()'>Anchor</a>
```

---

## Update

Visit this jsbin

**http://jsbin.com/icUTUjI/1/edit**

May be this will help you a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: do i need to pass parameter in function...?

Comment: No you just need to call your function, the function `newwin()` takes care for all your problems

Comment: but instead of 1 i need to pass on value from php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38985/discussion-between-ankur-dhanuka-and-dpak-sharma)

Answer (score 12):

Fun! There are a few things to tease out here:

- `$leadID` seems to be a php string. Make sure it gets printed in the right place. Also be aware of all the risks involved in passing your own strings around, like [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. There’s really no excuse for having Internet-facing production code not running [on a solid framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks).
- Strings in Javascript (like in PHP and usually HTML) need to be enclosed in `"` or `'` characters. Since you’re already inside both `"` and `'`, you’ll want to *escape* whichever you choose. `\'` to escape the PHP quotes, or `&apos;` to escape the HTML quotes.
- [`<a />` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Example) are commonly used for “hyper”links, and almost always with a `href` attribute to indicate their destination, like this: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google homepage</a>`.
- You’re trying to double up on watching when the user clicks. Why? Because a standard click both activates the link (causing the browser to navigate to whatever URL, even that executes Javascript), and “triggers” the onclick event. Tip: Add a `return false;` to a Javascript event to suppress default behavior.
- Within Javascript, `onclick` doesn’t mean anything on its own. That’s because [`onclick` is a *property*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick), and not a *variable*. There has to be a reference to some *object*, so it knows whose `onclick` we’re talking about! One such object is `window`. You could write `<a href="javascript:window.onclick = location.reload;">Activate me to reload when anything is clicked</a>`.
- Within HTML, `onclick` can mean something on its own, as long as its part of an HTML tag: `<a href="#" onclick="location.reload(); return false;">`. I bet you had this in mind.
- Big difference between those two kinds of `=` assignments. The Javascript `=` expects something that hasn’t been run yet. You can wrap things in a `function` block to signal code that should be run later, if you want to specify some arguments now (like I didn’t above with `reload`): `<a href="javascript:window.onclick = function () { window.open( ... ) };"> ...`.
- Did you know you don’t even need to use Javascript to signal the browser to open a link in a new window? There’s a special target attribute for that: `<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google homepage</a>`.

Hope those are useful.

Comment: No one say I didn’t try! `<a href='#' onclick='window.open("lead_data.php?leadid=1", "myWin", "scrollbars=yes, width=400, height=650"); return false;'>1</a>`

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka Not useful? You're not keen on learning, are you?

Answer (score 5):

You should read up on the [`onclick`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) html attribute and the [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) documentation. Below is what you want.

```html
<a href='#' onclick='window.open("http://www.google.com", "myWin", "scrollbars=yes,width=400,height=650"); return false;'>1</a>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBcVN/

Answer (score 3):

Use the `onclick` as an attribute of your `a`, not part of the `href`

```
<a onclick='window.open("lead_data.php?leadid=1", myWin, scrollbars=yes, width=400, height=650);'>1</a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wt5La/

Comment: The path/url attribute still needs some quotes.

Comment: please create fiddle for it